# Printing a string in MIPs without the use of la

Tags: arrays, mips

well I've got an assignment to create an int array, sum them up, and print the average. All while not using la. Well I've got the main structure all well and done but the one thing I'm having trouble with is printing my strings for the prompts.

What I need to know is have far I need to move the pointer I have to access the strings I have in my .data section. Below is my data section...

```
    .data
size: .word 10
nums: .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

prompt: .asciiz "\nEnter ten integers : "

theaverage : .asciiz "\nThe average is "
greaterthan : .asciiz "\nThese integers are greater than the average   \n----------------------------------------- "
lessthan : .asciiz "\nThese integers are less than the average \n-------------------------------------- "
```

The question I have is how far do I have to increment $t0 to access my variables prompt, the average, greaterthan, and lessthan. I'm able to get through the array perfectly fine on my own. I start out with $t0 at the base address of the .data section like so...

```
main :
        lui $t0, 0x1001 # Base address of .data segment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the size of each element stored in the data section.

For instance, each `.word` consumes 4 bytes, and each character consumes 1 byte.

You also have to take into account that `.asciiz` strings end with an null byte.

So, for example, to know the starting address of `prompt` you would have to add the base address plus 4 (`size`) plus 40 (`nums` array).

Then, `theaverage` starts at `prompt` address plus 17 (`\n` counts as 1 byte, and the ending `null` are both accounted); and so forth for the other labels.

Note also that is more likely that .data segment starts at address 0x1000 and not 0x1001 as you stated.